# Json request in MVC 5 is missing the last select list item in cascading drop down

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, cascadingdropdown

When selecting items inside of my cascading dropdowns, I am missing the last item to be selected. But when I select an option, it finally populates the last item in the list, and it would then be visible and selectable.

ViewModel

```
 public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CyspCityStateCountry { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a country.")]
    public int CTRY_ID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetCanMexUsa { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a state.")]
    public int StprId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> StprStateProvince { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a city.")]
    public int CITY_ID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetCityStprCtry { get; set; }
```

JsonRequest

```
        public JsonResult GetStateList(int ctryId)
    {
        _db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        var stateList =
            _db.TRLOG_CORN_ANALY_StprStateProvinces.Where(x => x.StprCtryId == ctryId).Select(a => new
            {
                a.StprId,
                a.StprName
            }).ToList();
        return Json(stateList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public JsonResult GetCityList(int cyspStprId)
    {
        _db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        var cityList =
            _db.TRLOG_CORN_ANALY_GetCityStprCtryByCysp().Where(t => t.STPR_ID == cyspStprId).ToList();
        return Json(cityList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Razor

```
  <div class="col-xs-4 input-group-sm">
     <div class="form-group">
      <label class="DBlock">Country</label>
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CTRY_ID, new SelectList(Model.GetCanMexUsa, "Value", "Text"), "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control input-sm", style = "display: block"})
      <p>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CTRY_ID)</p>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-4 input-group-sm">
     <div class="form-group">
     <label class="DBlock">State</label>
     @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StprId, new SelectList(" "), "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control input-sm", style = "display: block"})
   <p>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StprId)</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 input-group-sm">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="DBlock">City</label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CITY_ID, new SelectList(" "), "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control input-sm", style = "display: block" })
    <p>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CITY_ID)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

JQuery

```
$(function() {
        $("#CTRY_ID").chosen().change(function() {
            $.get("/Form/GetStateList",
                { CTRY_ID: $("#CTRY_ID").trigger("chosen:updated").val() },
                function(data) {
                    $("#StprId").empty().append($('<option></option>').val('').text('--Select--'));
                    $.each(data,
                        function(index, row) {
                            $("#StprId").chosen().trigger("chosen:updated").append("<option value = '" +
                                row.StprId +
                                "'>" +
                                row.StprName +
                                "</option>");
                        });
                });
            $("#StprId").chosen().change(function() {
                $.get("/Shipment/GetCityList",
                    { cyspStprId: $("#StprId").trigger("chosen:updated").val() },
                    function(data) {
                        "use strict";
                        $("#CITY_ID").empty().append($('<option></option>').val('').text('--Select--'));
                        $.each(data,
                            function(index, row) {
                                $("#CITY_ID").chosen().trigger("chosen:updated").append("<option value = '" +
                                    row.CYSP_CITY_ID +
                                    "'>" +
                                    row.CITY_NAME +
                                    "</option>");
                            });
                    });
            });
        });
    });
```

[Inspection View of States](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJ7hB.png)

The last selection that should be view-able is Wyoming, but my select list stops at Wisconsin. But, when you inspect the drop down the last item Wyoming is view-able in the inspection view but not selectable until another option in the drop-down is selected and then Wyoming shows up and is selectable. I am at a loss as to what to do to fix it, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please don't add code as images. Use a code field instead. See markdown styles here https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be calling chosen.trigger("chosen:updated") before adding the option to the list, and calling it once for every option. Try moving that call to after the $.each so chosen can pick up all the option elements and only once.

Comment: I moved it to after the .each and it wouldn't even populate the list.

Comment: I removed it from the { CTRY_ID: $("#CTRY_ID").trigger("chosen:updated").val() }, which gave me the list without the last one and wouldn't reset if the selection was changed.

Comment: Then I removed it from $("#StprId").chosen().trigger("chosen:updated").append("<option value....and it wouldn't populate the list.

Comment: I'm posting from mobile so it's hard to edit code right now. Go back to the code in your post and switch the trigger and append calls. That should do it.

Comment: Excellent! I thought it would be something small. Thank you very much.